# RAM upgrade causes firefox, compiz crashes, even kernel panic on HP Pavilion

Tags: nvidia, kernel, hardware, ram, hp-pavilion

I use a HP Pavilion dv6500, and I recently upgraded my ram on my laptop from 1G to 4G, but I keep getting random issues. Here are a few:

- When watching youtube videos / vlc videos after a long period of time, the whole system will crash and kernel panic (I can't CTRL+ALT+F1 to a new terminal, Caps lock light flashing)
- Firefox will crash randomly
- Compiz has "crashed" once or twice, not sure if related.
- Nautilus has crashed
- NetworkManager no longer saves my wifi password (possibly unrelated)

I thought it might be my memory controller, so I did an `lshw` and found that there was an nVidia memory controller that was unclaimed. It's called `MCP67 Memory Controller`. After a google search, I found [a link to a similar problem on Gentoo](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-909124-start-0.html).

So I went into the BIOS and did a Memory Test, but it passed. On the article above, it talks about adjusting DRAM timings, but my BIOS doesn't have such a feature.

Is this typical for a quick-and-dirty RAM upgrade? Should I reinstall ubuntu / would that help? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you revert to your original memory sticks, does the problem persist?

Comment: Try to compile kernel and activate options matching to your hardware.

Comment: I think it is a hardware problem with you new memory or a compatibility issue between the different ram sticks. Do a memtest to confirm.

Comment: @yilmi That's my next plan - make myself a gentoo build.

Comment: @kiloseven No, the problem goes away. I'm guessing HP put something proprietary in there somewhere.

Comment: OK, do you have a pair of 1GB sticks? Or, can you try it with just _one_ of the 2GB sticks (yes, 10% performance hit) as I am wondering if there's a issue w/ the memory sticks themselves which the memory test didn't find.

Comment: Run the memtest86 option when you boot the ubuntu live cd.  Let it go for an hour or so and you will probably find the memory is bad.  The lshw and unclaimed memory controller is a red herring; it is always unclaimed.

Comment: Well, that's good news at least (actually I guess not cause it doesn't solve the problem!). I just did a memtest using an old 9.10 cd (the only one I could find that did memtests from the cd), but it says that all the tests passed. I'm just going to compile my own kernel with gentoo and have a separate lubuntu partition, and post my results. Thanks though.

Comment: So I just installed lubuntu 32 bit, and I had some episodes of the same problem. I tried compiling ghc from source, and midway it cuts out saying there was a bus error. My guess is that it's from using 32 bit on a 4G+ memory system. Probably wrong there, but it may have something to do with how the kernel evaluates address spaces, and thus I feel like the 32 bit restriction might have something to do with it. I'm installing lubuntu 64 right now, will update with results.